# Copying generics to an array?

Tags: java, generics

The task specification is as follows:
"Your task is to create Multiplicator that receives Folders with anything that can be copied (i.e. implementing Copy interface) and creates an array of Folders with copies of the original Folder content."

I am trying to figure out how to add objects into the array. However, when I run the code that I have written, I get an output of null.

How can I add generic objects into an array?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Class to work with
 */
class Multiplicator {
    public static <T extends Copy<T>> Folder<T>[] multiply(Folder<T> folder, int arraySize) {
        // Method to implement
        Folder myFolder = new Folder();
        Folder<T>[] folderArray = new Folder[arraySize];
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            folderArray[i] = (Folder<T>) myFolder.get();
        }
        return folderArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Well done!");
    }

}

// Don't change the code below
interface Copy<T> {
    T copy();
}

class Folder<T> {

    private T item;

    public void put(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

    public T get() {
        return this.item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Folder` implementation totally contradicts the question you've asked

Comment: @ShyamBaitmangalkar
I am still new to generics but I thought I am to create a Folder object so that I can use the T generic helper methods for my Multiiplicator class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not how you created a new array of a generic type. In fact, you created a `Folder<T>[]` correctly, using `new Folder[arraySize]`. Yes, there is a warning, but that is because of a restriction/flaw in Java's type system.

The reason why it's all null, is because you created an empty folder, `Folder myFolder = new Folder();`, and put its contents (`null`) into the array (`folderArray[i] = (Folder<T>) myFolder.get();`).

According to the task description, you should be *copying* the contents of the folder provided as one of the parameters, `folder`:

```
public static <T extends Copy<T>> Folder<T>[] multiply(Folder<T> folder, int arraySize) {

    Folder<T>[] folderArray = new Folder[arraySize];

    // for arraySize times...
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        // create a new, empty folder
        Folder<T> newFolder = new Folder<>();
        // put the copy of the parameter folder's contents into the new folder
        newFolder.put(folder.get().copy());
        // put the new folder into the array
        folderArray[i] = newFolder;
    }
    return folderArray;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am new to generics and can see now that I should create an instance of Folder<Generic type> and not an object of Folder.

Just to confirm, when I instantiate Folder<T>, I am able to access the methods in classes and interfaces associated with T?

Comment: @RikoKurahashi What do you mean by "associated with `T`"? You are able to access `copy` here because in the method signature, it is said that `T extends Copy<T>`.

Comment: My apologies, I was looking at Folder<T> copy and how it links to T extends Copy<T>.
With Folder<T> copy = new Folder<>();, this allows the Copy interface to work as T is being utilized?
Edit: I will try to search for documentation about the differences between creating objects and Folder<Generic> as I think that is where my confusion lays.

Comment: @RikoKurahashi I've realised I might have used some confusing names here. I've edited my answer. Essentially, `folder.get()` returns a `T` because `folder` is a `Folder<T>` (look at the parameter!). Now, why can you use `.copy()` on `folder.get()`? Because `T` is also a `Copy<T>` according to the constraint in the method signature.

Comment: @RikoKurahashi For the difference between `Folder` and `Folder<T>`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: Thank you.  I understand why we need <T> for instantiation as it links to the other methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216200/discussion-between-sweeper-and-riko-kurahashi).